# jQuery prevent multiple submisssions before response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I would do this in JS fiddle, but I can't get the POST echoer to work, so I'll make an example here.  Let's pretend that `someApi` returns "bar"

JS / jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function(event) {
        getSomeData();
    });
    function getSomeData() {
        $("div").text("Foo = ");
        $.get("someApi", function(i) {
            $("div").append(i);
        });
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

There maybe some typos here, but please ignore them as I've written an example on-the-fly.  What happens is when `<button>` is clicked once, all works well.  The AJAX function is called and the `<div>` is appended when the response comes.  If I wait for the response and click again, the `<div>` is overwritten with `Foo =` and then appended.  The issue comes when the user becomes inpatient and clicks `<button>` multiple times, spawning multiple AJAX requests.  This ends up with "bar" being appended multiple times.  Is there a feature within JS / jQuery to avoid sending multiple requests to the same URL?  I DON'T mean I want a `async = false` scenario; I know this would work, but would also slow the application down.  I also know I could add an if loop that checks if bar has already been appended.  What I'm asking for is a proper JS / jQuery `.blockMultipleRequest();` kind of thing.

Comment: Why don't you just disable the button from the moment it has been clicked until the AJAX call has completed?

Comment: The button is just an example, come production it might be a different trigger.

Comment: Yeah its the standard practice that you should disable the button or better hide it on ajax requests and show a tine wait loader gif image in place of it.. As how will the user know what is happening on ajax? On full posts, the browser shows the messages to the user bit in case of ajax, we should show something.

Comment: Lol when i clicked on submit comment, even SO did the same :-D

Comment: As I've just said, @guurav, a button may not be the trigger.  I know what can be done in this sense, as mentioned in the question.  All I want to know is if there is a way in JS / jQ to detect multiple AJAX requests.  That's all!  If not, I'll write one myself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there's a plugin for that. You could use `.one()` in this way:

```
function bindButton() {
    $('button').one('click', function(event) {
        getSomeData();
    });
}

function getSomeData()
    $("div").text("Foo = ");
    $.get("someApi", function(i) {
        $("div").append(i);
        bindButton();
    });
}

$(function() {
    bindButton();
});
```

In function `bindButton()` you define your event handler with `one()`. Once button has been clicked event is removed until response of AJAX call, then function `bindButton()` is called again and event handler gets bound again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the global AJAX event handlers that jQuery provides and then do stuff depending on the request.

- [`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) when any request starts (the `event`, `jqXHR`, and `settings` properties are sent to the handler, so you can then do URL-specific actions by evaluating `settings.url`
- [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) when any request completes.

You could then use an object that keeps track of AJAX calls per URL, which can consult before sending off another request (e.g. only if it not currently in an active/pending state).